# How to sort multiple columns in html table? I need to revise the function I believe to sort all of the columns,

Tags: html, sorting, html-table

I think this is where my issue arises. I've gotten it to work with three columns, but I'm not sure where to go to have it sort multiple. I'm sure it is in this function portion. Please let me know if you need more info.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=Windows-1252">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var people, asc1 = 1,
        asc2 = 1,
        asc3 = 1,
        asc4 = 1,
        asc5 = 1,
        asc6 = 1,
        asc7 = 1,
        asc8 = 1,
        asc9 = 1,
        asc10 = 1,
        asc11 = 1,
        asc12 = 1;
    window.onload = function () {
        people = document.getElementById("people");
    }

function sort_table(tbody, col, asc)
{
var rows = tbody.rows;
var rlen = rows.length;
var arr = new Array();
var i, j, cells, clen;
// fill the array with values from the table
for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++)
{
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    clen = cells.length;
    arr[i] = new Array();
  for(j = 0; j < clen; j++) { arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML; }
}
// sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
arr.sort(function(a, b)
{
    var retval=0;
    var fA=parseFloat(a[col]);
    var fB=parseFloat(b[col]);
    if(a[col] != b[col])
    {
        if((fA==a[col]) && (fB==b[col]) ){ retval=( fA > fB ) ? asc : 
-1*asc; } //numerical
        else { retval=(a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1*asc;}
    }
    return retval;      
});
for(var rowidx=0;rowidx<rlen;rowidx++)
{
    for(var colidx=0;colidx<arr[rowidx].length;colidx++){ 
tbody.rows[rowidx].cells[colidx].innerHTML=arr[rowidx][colidx]; }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you meann by sortingn multiple columns? When you click on the top of 1 it sorts or how you mean?

Comment: Yes when the header is clicked it sorts alphabetically and numerically. It works for three columns atm but not for the 12 I need.

Answer (score 0):

I have a website with the same functionality and this is the function i use. And this SHOULD work for all table sizes.

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("totemTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
switching = false;
rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
/*Loop through all table rows (except the
first, which contains table headers):*/
for (i = 2; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
  //start by saying there should be no switching:
  shouldSwitch = false;
  /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
  one from current row and one from the next:*/
  x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
  y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
  /*check if the two rows should switch place,
  based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
  if (dir == "asc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  } else if (dir == "desc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (shouldSwitch) {
  /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
  and mark that a switch has been done:*/
  rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
  switching = true;
  //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
  switchcount ++; 
   } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc", set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please check above to see if you can figure where I'm going wrong

Comment: Any Ideas @Jari Flederick?

Answer (score 0):

I've went wrong somewhere and not sure where at, but I think your function should work but maybe I'm inputing it wrong?                                          '

```
        var people, asc1 = 1,
        asc2 = 1,
        asc3 = 1,
        asc4 = 1,
        asc5 = 1,
        asc6 = 1,
        asc7 = 1,
        asc8 = 1,
        asc9 = 1,
        asc10 = 1,
        asc11 = 1,
        asc12 = 1;
    window.onload = function () {
        people = document.getElementById("people");
    }

function sortTable(n) {
var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
switching = true;
//Set the sorting direction to ascending:
dir = "asc"; 
/*Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:*/
while (switching) {
//start by saying: no switching is done:
switching = false;
rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
/*Loop through all table rows (except the
first, which contains table headers):*/
for (i = 2; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
//start by saying there should be no switching:
shouldSwitch = false;
/*Get the two elements you want to compare,
one from current row and one from the next:*/
x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
/*check if the two rows should switch place,
based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
if (dir == "asc") {
if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
  //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
  shouldSwitch= true;
  break;
}
} else if (dir == "desc") {
if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
  //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
  shouldSwitch= true;
  break;
}
}
}
if (shouldSwitch) {
/*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
and mark that a switch has been done:*/
rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
switching = true;
//Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
switchcount ++; 
} else {
  /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc", set the 
direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
  if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
    dir = "desc";
    switching = true;
  }
}
}
}
</script>'
```

And the table:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 0, asc1); asc1 *= -1;asc2 = 1;asc3 = 1;asc4 
= 1;asc5 = 1;asc6 = 1;asc7 = 1;asc 8 = 1;asc 9 = 1;asc10 = 1;asc 11= 1;asc 
12 = 1;">Player ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 1, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1;asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">Team ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">Role ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 3, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">KDA ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 4, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">Kills ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 5, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">Deaths ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 6, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">Assists ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 7, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">KP(%) ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 8, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">CS(Total) ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 9, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">CS(p/m) ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 10, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">Gold(~total) ↕</th>
<th onclick="sort_table(people, 11, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; 
asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1; asc7 = 1; asc 8 = 1; asc 9 = 1; asc10 = 1; asc 
11= 1; asc 12 = 1;">Games Played ↕</th>


</tr>
</thead>
    <tbody id="people">

<tr>
  <td class="Player-cell">Anivia HD</td>
  <td class="Team-cell">Apox</td>
  <td class="Role-cell">Mid</td>
  <td class="KDA-cell">4.85</td>
  <td class="Kills-cell">31</td>
  <td class="Deaths-cell">29</td>
  <td class="Assists-cell">33</td>
  <td class="KP(%)-cell">62.25</td>
  <td class="CS(Total)-cell">1434</td>
  <td class="CS(p/m)-cell">6.30</td>
  <td class="Gold(~total)-cell">77</td>
  <td class="Games Played-cell">8</td>
</tr>
</table>
```